# Jersey POST xml and javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException with ServletFilter

Tags: jaxb, jersey, servlet-filters

I have a Jersey POST REST service that both produces and consumes MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.
I also have a ServletFilter that does some authentication:

```
 if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

//read headers

//authenticate

filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

...
```

Without the filter in the picture, my REST api works perfectly.
With the filter, I do see the response XML in Firebug but with a 400 Status code: 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.]

The posts I read alluded to the filter altering the response, but I really don't know what to do to fix this.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I used the ContainerRequestFilter instead of a javax.servlet.Filter and things work well.